# Function to polynomial equation in GF(2)

Tags: s-boxes, algebraic-attack, sat

Let `F(a,b,c,d,e)` be a function that returns the `ith` bit of `0x3A5C742E`, where `i=a*2^4+b*2^3+c*2^2+d*2+e` and i is the offset from the least significant bit.
The author [Page 33/200, chapter 2.3.4](http://drum.lib.umd.edu/bitstream/handle/1903/7202/umi-umd-4594.pdf;sequence=1) states that in order to find the polynomial for the equivalent output you can use k-maps.
Later he states that the equation after the calculations is:

`NLF(a,b,c,d,e) = d+e+ac+ae+bc+be+cd+de+ade+ace+abd+abc`

Here is my k-map calculation:

```
     00   01   11   10
000   0    1    1    1  
001   0    1    0    0  
011   1    1    0    1  
010   0    0    0    1  
110   0    1    1    0  
111   1    1    0    0  
101   1    0    0    1  
100   0    0    1    1
```

Where rows are `abc`, and columns are `de`

Now from this figure I cannot see how it is possible to generate the given equation. There are elimination of only 1 variable. So all the generated equations should have been at least of 4 degree.

So the question is, how is his equation generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula
$$ d+e+ac+ae+bc+be+cd+de+ade+ace+abd+abc $$
is in **algebraic normal form** (ANF).
That is the *unique* representation of our boolean function with respect to the $\mathbb F_2$-basis $\{a^ib^jc^kd^le^m\mid i,j,k,l,m\in\{0,1\}\}$ of the space of boolean functions $\mathbb F_2^5\to\mathbb F_2$.
In particular, note "$+$" is *exclusive* or.

I do not think the Karnaugh map is very helpful in that case, since grouping the $1$ entries in the table becomes a bit tricky, and since you have to avoid negations. In the end, it works, but it's more involved than just drawing a few rectangles and reading off the right terms.

Instead, the algebraic description above provides an easy iterative method to compute the ANF. (See also [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/109365).)
Basically, the ANF for our function $f$ will look like this:
$$
f(a,b,c,d,e) = 
x_0+
x_aa+x_bb+x_cc+x_dd+x_ee+
x_{ab}ab+x_{ac}ac+x_{ad}ad+x_{ae}ae+x_{bc}bc+x_{bd}bd+x_{be}be+x_{cd}cd+x_{ce}ce+x_{de}de+
x_{abc}abc+x_{abd}abd+x_{abe}abe+x_{acd}acd+x_{ace}ace+x_{ade}ade+x_{bcd}bcd+x_{bce}bce+x_{bde}bde+x_{cde}cde+
x_{abcd}abcd+x_{abce}abce+x_{abde}abde+x_{acde}acde+x_{bcde}bcde+
x_{abcde}abcde
\text,
$$
and we are interested in computing the *unique* coefficients $x_\ast\in\{0,1\}$.
To do so, we restrict the target function $f$: Setting enough variables to zero will simplify the above formula sufficiently to fully determine another coefficient.

- To start with, we consider the "restriction" $f(0,0,0,0,0)$. By the above formula, this is just $x_0$.
- Next, we consider $f(a,0,0,0,0)=x_0+x_aa$: Since $x_0$ is already known, $x_a$ may be recovered as $f(1,0,0,0,0)+x_0$ (modulo $2$ of course). The coefficients $x_b$ through $x_e$ are computed analogously.
- For $x_{ab}$, consider $f(a,b,0,0,0)=x_0+x_aa+x_bb+x_{ab}ab$: The coefficients $x_0$, $x_a$ and $x_b$ are already known, so we can compute $x_{ab}=f(1,1,0,0,0)+x_0+x_a+x_b$. Again, $x_{ac}$ through $x_{de}$ work exactly the same.
- Repeating this procedure will eventually yield all the coefficients.

In case you just want the result without going through the process manually, note that [sage](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/cryptography/sage/crypto/boolean_function.html#sage.crypto.boolean_function.BooleanFunction.algebraic_normal_form) provides the relevant functionality.